# Did the author need to check this fact? ("Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.

On p.41, the author wrote the following:

> We now claim that between any two right cosets $Ha$ and $Hb$ of $H$ in $G$ there exists a one-to-one correspondence, namely, with any element $ha\in Ha$, where $h\in H$, associate the   element $hb\in Hb$. Clearly this mapping is onto $Hb$. We aver that it is a one-to-one correspondence, for if $h_1b=h_2b$, with $h_1,h_2\in H$, then by the cancellation law in $G$, $h_1=h_2$ and so $h_1a=h_2a$.

The author wrote "***this mapping***".

But he didn't check the following:  Let $c\in Ha$. Let $c=h_1a=h_2a$. Then, by the cancellation law in $G$, $h_1=h_2$. So, $Ha\ni c=ha\mapsto hb\in Hb$ is a mapping.

Did the author need to check the above fact?

Comment: You did check it though, so it's all good, no? I mean, yes, you can, but routine statements like $ha=ka$ implies $h=k$ will usually be glossed over in order to get anywhere.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven But the author checked this mapping is injective by the cancellation law in $G$. I think it is unfair that he didn't check $Ha\ni c=ha\mapsto hb\in Hb$ is a mapping by the cancellation law.

Comment: My guess is that he already, before, proves that the elements of $Ha$ are of the form $ha$ for $h\in H$, and any two such elements are distinct, before this statement. That's what I would have done.